# Phonegap -Leaflat map fill up remaining site

Tags: javascript, html, css, cordova, flexbox

I am using Leaflat to display a map, I want it to fill the remaining space, for that I wanted to use the flex boxes, but the map is not even displayed, it is only displaey if I define it a height in px.

**JavaScript**

```
    var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

    L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      maxZoom: 18,
      attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
        '<a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
        'Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
      id: 'examples.map-i875mjb7'
    }).addTo(map);
```

**CSS**

```
    body {
      padding: 0 !important;
      margin: 0 !important;
      height: 100% !important;
      display: flex !important;
      flex-flow: column wrap !important;
      height: 100% !important;
    }
    #content {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    } 

    .content-box {} .content-box .run {} 

    .content-box .run.data {
      order: 1;
      flex: 0 1 auto;
    }
    .content-box .run.data > h1 {
      text-align: center;
    }
    .content-box .run.map {
      order: 2;
      flex: 1 1 auto;
      width: 100%;
    }
```

**HTML**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <title>App</title>
      <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.js"></script>
      <link href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>

    <body>
      <div id="app">
        <div id="content" class="content-box">
          <div class="run data">
            <p>Some content</p>
            <p>....</p>
          </div>
          <div class="run map" id="map">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have tried several things from similar questions here on stackoverflow but none of them could solve my problem.
If I add `position: fixed;` to `#content` in my css file and add `height: 100%;` to `.content-box .run-map` I the map is sized correctly at the first moment, but then after clicking comething it glitches and no longer correctly, I tried something with `position: fixed;` but this had not helped.
How can I make the map fill the rest of my site?

Answer (score 0):

What I did is to set html height to 100%.

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Sadly, it does not work for me. Would it be possible that you could show me your whole code, I would really appreciate that. :-)